# How was the product rule expanded?

Tags: calculus

I am wondering how line 2 came about from the picture. I tried to expand and got a totally different value. Can some explain. Also, if you wish to see enlarged use Zooom [image]

Comment: Expand what exactly? Note that $-f(x+h)g(x) + f(x+h)g(x) = 0$. It's simply a neat trick so that we can group the functions and take the limits of the products to obtain the product rule.

Comment: I used to say in Analysis class that the judicious addition of zero or multiplication by 1 often yields a smart solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Just observe that
$$
\color{red}{f(x+h)}g(x+h)-\color{red}{f(x+h)}g(x)+f(x+h)\color{blue}{g(x)}-f(x)\color{blue}{g(x)}
$$ rewrites
$$
\color{red}{f(x+h)}\left(g(x+h)-g(x)\right)+\color{blue}{g(x)}\left(f(x+h)-f(x)\right)
$$ and divide by $h$.